# weeknumbers ms access query

Tags: ms-access, week-number, datepart

I would like to get weeknumbers in ms access according to:

https://www.kalender-365.nl/kalender-2021.html

My expression:

`test: DatePart("ww",#01/01/2021#,2,2)`

This returns `1` instead of week `53`. What can I do to return `53`?

syntax:

`DatePart(datepart, date, firstdayofweek, firstweekofyear)`

> 2 = Monday (firstdayofweek)
>
> 2 = Use the first week in the year that has at least 4 days (firstdayofyear)

Comment: AFAIK Access does not support true ISO week-numbers - you'll have to do the calculation yourself.

Comment: aha thx. That clarifies things.

Comment: `DatePart("ww",#01/01/2021#,2,2)` returns correctly 53, not 1.

Comment: Well my access (2007) strangely returns 1 with `DatePart("ww",#01/01/2021#,2,2)` when creating a query in design view (same code does return 53 when for example using this code here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_ms_datepart&ss=-1).

Your function (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65597984/2968136), however works perfect! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You may need the matching ISO year as well:

```vb
Public Const MaxWeekValue           As Integer = 53
Public Const MinWeekValue           As Integer = 1
Public Const MaxMonthValue          As Integer = 12
Public Const MinMonthValue          As Integer = 1



' Returns the ISO 8601 week of a date.
' The related ISO year is returned by ref.
'
' 2016-01-06. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function Week( _
    ByVal Date1 As Date, _
    Optional ByRef IsoYear As Integer) _
    As Integer

    Dim Month       As Integer
    Dim Interval    As String
    Dim Result      As Integer
    
    Interval = "ww"
    
    Month = VBA.Month(Date1)
    ' Initially, set the ISO year to the calendar year.
    IsoYear = VBA.Year(Date1)
    
    Result = DatePart(Interval, Date1, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)
    If Result = MaxWeekValue Then
        If DatePart(Interval, DateAdd(Interval, 1, Date1), vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays) = MinWeekValue Then
            ' OK. The next week is the first week of the following year.
        Else
            ' This is really the first week of the next ISO year.
            ' Correct for DatePart bug.
            Result = MinWeekValue
        End If
    End If
        
    ' Adjust year where week number belongs to next or previous year.
    If Month = MinMonthValue Then
        If Result >= MaxWeekValue - 1 Then
            ' This is an early date of January belonging to the last week of the previous ISO year.
            IsoYear = IsoYear - 1
        End If
    ElseIf Month = MaxMonthValue Then
        If Result = MinWeekValue Then
            ' This is a late date of December belonging to the first week of the next ISO year.
            IsoYear = IsoYear + 1
        End If
    End If
    
    ' IsoYear is returned by reference.
    Week = Result
        
End Function
```